# How do I infer fan-out in Altera opencl design?

Tags: opencl, fpga, intel-fpga

[image: 2-D PE array and local memory interconnection]I am currently implementing a 2-D PE array in my Altera openCL design on PFGA. In this implementation, each BRAM is feeding multiple PEs at the same time, but looks like this fan-out design cannot be inferred by the compiler. Anyone got any idea how this can be achieved in openCL C code?

Comment: (Just a grain of salt)I don't have this hardware but did you try __constant qualifier? Because constants are meant to be broadcasted to all workitems as read-only variables. Maybe you can first get data to __local variable then broadcast to all group-items? I heard it takes hours to compile a kernel, is it still that long?

Comment: Thanks for replying! I did this in a task kernel (PEs are instantiated by function calls to normal mac function, and hardware are replicated by unrolling loop twice)

Comment: We need code and an error message to help you.